# Android Webview is not loading redirected url

Tags: android, android-webview

I am try to load URL which internally redirect another URL in android WebView, but it is showing blank page. I have checked and found that I am trying to load http://erp1.stmarysschoolbxr.org/StudentReportCard.aspx?card=admitcard&AdmNo=22L001 which indirect to another URL http://erp1.stmarysschoolbxr.org/ReportPage.aspx but it is showing blank page. But when I try to load it in browser, it is loading fine.

Below is my webview code

```
binding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        binding.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                hideLoader();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                hideLoader();
            }
        });

        binding.webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to WebView [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)):

```
Note: Do not call WebView#loadUrl(String) with the request's URL and then return true. 
This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. 
The correct way to continue loading a given URL is to simply return false, 
without calling WebView#loadUrl(String).
```

just return false in shouldOverrideUrlLoading without calling`view.loadUrl(url);`

Comment: I have change it  Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
but it is not working means, page is not loading. Only loader is showing, onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) is not calling.